# Direct link to asynchronously loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

On my website I have a menu where loads content asynchronously. Is there a way to provide a link to each item on the menu?

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    init();
    $(window).resize(init);

    $('#floatMenu,#smallMenu').find('>a').click(function()
    {
        var t = this;
        $('#wynik').animate({opacity:0}, 'fast', function()
        {
            $(this).load(t.href, function()
            {
                $(this).animate({opacity:1}, 'fast');
            })
        });

        //$('#wynik').load(this.href);

        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    }).first().click();
});
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="list-group" id="smallMenu">
                <a href="text/bc/5" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item active">TEXT</a>
                <a href="text/bc/1" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item">TEXT</a>
                <a href="text/bc/2" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item">TEXT</a>
                <a href="text/bc/3" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item">TEXT</a>
                <a href="text/bc/4" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item">TEXT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div id="wynik">
                {* Here is content loading. *}
            </div>
        </div>                   
    </div>
</div>
```

Is the id in the link would have done?

Comment: What does a link to a menu item menu?

Comment: asynchronously loads the content